# How to create a get() member function for a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, wrapper

My problem is std::tuple has no member function like

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1,2,"foo");
t.get(1);
```

how can I implement such a function when I create a wrapper class arround std::tuple

Comment: Why can't you just use `std::get<1>(t)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Such a function cannot exist (in current C++ standards) because function arguments are a run-time mechanism, but return types need to be known at compile time. So the latter cannot depend on the former.

Use [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) instead:

```
auto v = std::get<1>(someTuple);
```

Comment: While it is, indeed, true, I was always wondering why `get` is implemented as a free function and not tuple member function. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @SergeyA So that in templates you don't have to write `foo.template get<0>()`.

Comment: @T.C., true. I found it and even posted as a separate answer. Wanted to remove my asking question, than forgot :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from a tuple you should use `std::get<0>(tuple)`

You can't have a `get` function like you want, because tuple elements are not necessarily of the same type (in your example you have ints and a string). What would the return type of this `get` function be?

You can add a template get function, so that `derived_tuple.get<0>()` will return the first element.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two questions here. The first is

> why get has a template integral argument rather than a accepting this
>   value as a function argument.

This has been answered.

The other question is

> why get is a free function rather than a member function

To this the answer seem to be - so that called on templated types, it would not require usage of keyword `typename`. Example. Suppose, tuple would have a get as a member, it would have to be called like that in below code:

```
template <class T> void foo(T tuple) {
    tuple.template get<1>() = 42;
}
```

This `template` is certainly a nuisance.